# What is supposed to be a random variable is always generating 5

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I've been teaching my self how to code C++ I purchased the book *Beginning C++ through game programming, third edition* by Michael Dawson and in it is a chapter you learn about loops. Towards the end of the chapter you make a game that jumbles a word. I wanted to go a little further with it and made 5 words that it picks at random. The problem is though, it always gets a value of 5, and therefore always selects the fifth word.

The code is as follows below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum fields {WORD, HINT, NUM_FIELDS};
    const int NUM_WORDS = 5;
    const string WORDS[NUM_WORDS][NUM_FIELDS] =
    {
        {"wall", "Do you feel you're banging your head against something?"},
        {"glasses", "These might help you see the answer"},
        {"labored", "Going slowly is it?"},
        {"persistent", "Keep at it"},
        {"jumble", "It's what this game is about!"}
    };

    srand(time(0));
    int preWord = rand() % 3;
    string tempWord;
    string theWord = WORDS[preWord][WORD]; //word to guess
    string theHint = WORDS[preWord][HINT]; //hint for word
    if (preWord = 1)
    {
        theWord = "wall";
        tempWord = "wall";
    }
    if (preWord = 2)
    {
        theWord = "glasses";
        tempWord = "glasses";
    }
    if (preWord = 3)
    {
        theWord = "labored";
        tempWord = "labored";
    }
    if (preWord = 4)
    {
        theWord = "persistent";
        tempWord = "persistent";
    }
    if (preWord = 5)
    {
        theWord = "jumble";
        tempWord = "jumble";
    }

    int length = theWord.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
            int index1 = (rand() % length);
            int index2 = (rand() % length);
            char temp = theWord[index1];
            theWord[index1] = theWord[index2];
            theWord[index2] = temp;
    }

    cout << "\t\t\tWelcome to the Word Jumble!\n\n";
    cout << "Unscramble the letters to make a word.\n";
    cout << "Enter 'hint' for a hint.\n";
    cout << "Enter 'quit' to quit the game.\n\n";
    cout << "The word is: " << theWord;
    cout << "\nvariable 'preWord' is: " << preWord;
    string guess;
    cout << "\n\nYour guess: ";
    cin >> guess;

    while ((guess != tempWord) && (guess != "quit"))
    {
        if (guess == "hint")
        {
            cout << theHint;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that's not it.";
        }

        cout <<"\n\nYour guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
    }

    if (guess == tempWord)
    {
        cout << "\nThat's it! You guessed it!\n";
    }

    cout << "\nThanks for playing!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question has quite a bit of code. For better help sooner, post a [SSCCE (link)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Here's a tip for you: `theWord = tempWord = WORDS[preWord][0];`, assuming it's always from 1 to 5.

Comment: That's the problem with true random numbers... how do you know that you are not just randomly getting all 5's? (It is also a problem with truly deterministic numbers, but who knows?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your conditions, you should write :

`if (preWord == x)`

which is a *comparison*, and not

`if (preWord = 5)`

which is an *assignment* - which means, when your code reach each of those `if` statements, it will actually ASSIGN the value to your variable - and since your 5th case if the last, it will ultimately change the value of `preWord` to `5`.

Comment: Additionally, seeding with the same value the random number generator is bound to cause less than truly random numbers.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well, `rand` is a pretty awful PRNG (a linear congruential generator) on most platforms anyway. Keeping that in mind, `time` is an easy way of at least getting *different* numbers on each run.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting preWord to 5. `if (preWord = 5)` not checking its equality. It should be `if (preWord == 5)`. Compile with warnings on and you should never have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out you are using the assignment operator(`=`) in your `if` statements as opposed to the equality operator(`==`) and therefore you are setting the value of `preWord` at ech `if` statement:

```
if (preWord = 5)
            ^
```

Should be:

```
if (preWord == 5)
            ^^
```

A habit I have gotten into is to put the literal on the other side of the equality like so:

```
if ( 5 == preWord )
```

If you had used `=` instead, it would be an outright error, in `gcc` you would see this message:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Of course turning on warning is always important and even if you used the form in your code you would have seen the following warning from `gcc`:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

Comment: +1 for using `lvalue`, but if `if (x = y)`, then your approach may not help:)

Comment: I use the other form. The compiler will warn you as long as you take the effort to turn warnings on, plus I find it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.  so all your `if`s need to use `==`...so change them as `if (preWord == 4)`

also, `int preWord = rand() % 3`; will generate random numbers in the range of 0 to 2. you need to use `int preWord = rand() % 5 +1` for generating numbers in the range of 1 to 5